# How to reinstall MariaDB?

Tags: encryption, mariadb

I had MariaDB 10.2 installed on Ubuntu 16.04. and I was using MariaDB encryption.

I had to uninstall MariaDB so I have uninstalled with following command:

```
apt purge mariadb-server -y
```

That uninstalled and left /var/lib/mysql + /etc/mysql unchanged, that's great.

Now problem is when I try to install again I get following error:

**InnoDB: Obtaining redo log encryption key version 1 failed (4294967295). Maybe the key or the required encryption key management plugin was not found.**

Plugin is here: /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/file_key_management.so

Keys are here: /etc/mysql/encrypt/keys.enc

Everything same as before.

Encryption keys are same, /usr/lib/mysql/plugin is there, mysql root pass is same...

Is there anything else related to encryption I need to take care of or?

Thank you